# How to share one session between react and django?

Tags: reactjs, django, session, cookies

I have frontend on React and backend on Django. They are running on two different ports.
The Goal is to save data from frontend to Django session and having access to it on every request.
But thing is it creates new session everytime I make a request
This is how request looks like on React side

```
 const data = await axios.post(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/urls/",
          qs.stringify({
            long: long_url,
            subpart: subpart,
          })
        );
```

And this is how it processed by view in Django where i am trying to create list of urls and append it every time.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def users_urls(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        long_url = request.POST.get('long')
        subpart = request.POST.get('subpart')

        if 'users_urls' in request.session:
            request.session['users_urls'].append(subpart)
        else:
            request.session['users_urls'] = [subpart]

        return Response(short_url)
```

It works as it should work when i make requests from Postman. But there is some trouble with react.
Help me please to figure this out

Comment: Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? You may have to add your cookie and crsf token in your headers